# R confusionMatrix with Caret Sensitivity vs Specificity

Tags: r

I ran confusion matrix on my test  prediction for Titanic

```
    library(caret)
confusionMatrix(pred, reference = r )

           Reference
Prediction FALSE TRUE
     FALSE    65   16
     TRUE     17   45
                                          
            Accuracy : 0.7692          
.... 
            Sensitivity : 0.7927          
            Specificity : 0.7377  

# Verification
(65+45)/(65+16+17+45)   #accuracy 0.7692 
   65/(65+17)           #Specificity : 0.7927       TN / (FP+TN)       
   45/(45+16)           #Sensitivity : 0.7377       TP / (TP+FN)
```

Looking at results I see that looks like TRUE / FALSE values are refersed, I tried to double check Sens and Spec using formulas which can be seen under #Verification section and looks like it's opposite. Being logical Sensitivity for my case TP /(TP+FN)   is:
*45/(45+16) = .73*  while on console this value shown as Specificity.
Who is wrong here ?  Or probably we just need reverse TRUE/False values in sets ?

My input is like below:

```
> str(r)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
> str(pred)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
>
```

Comment: You can use `confusionMatrix` argument `positive` to tell the function which is, well, the true value, there's no need to reverse the data values.

Comment: Your data is correct. just run `confusionMatrix(pred, reference = r , positive = 'TRUE')`

Comment: Thanks Rui and Onyambu!!!!! Works perfectly!!!